# How to do a distinct on Azure Application Insights Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I currently have the following query that I run with Application Insights Analytics:

```
customEvents 
| where name == 'Event Name 1' 
| project ['Column One'] = customDimensions['CD1'], ['Column Two'] = customDimensions['CD2'], ['Column Three'] = customDimensions['CD3']
```

The above query returns me some results like the following:

```
Column One | Column Two | Column Three
    A      |     2      |      D
    B      |     3      |      E
    C      |     2      |      F
```

How do I get the Query to return me only distinct values on column two?  Basically I want my result to be:

```
Column One | Column Two | Column Three
    A      |     2      |      D
    B      |     3      |      E
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So, the third record needs to be dropped completely? Or you want some aggregation logic applied for "A, C" and "D, F"?

Comment: the third record would be dropped completely

Comment: you can use "| summarize by ['Column Two']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
customEvents 
| where name == 'Event Name 1' 
| project ['Column One'] = tostring(customDimensions['CD1']),
          ['Column Two'] = tostring(customDimensions['CD2']),
          ['Column Three'] = tostring(customDimensions['CD3'])
| summarize any(['Column One']), any(['Column Three']) by ['Column Two']
```

This will pick up the first - not necessarily A in "A, C" pair. If you want to exclude "C" then you need to use other summarize aggregators like makelist/makeset.

Comment: Thank you sir!  This worked like a charm, I had played around with the summarize before, and was never able to get the correct syntax to get it past the "dynamic type not supported" error.  This is great, thank you so much.